# How to access the JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

how to access the JSON data every time i alert for the same it shows undefined . don't know where is the problem .

```
var FJS = FilterJS(art, '#movies', {

    template: '#movie-template',
    search: {
        ele: '#searchbox'
    },
    callbacks: {
        afterFilter: function(result) {
            $('#total_movies').text(result.length);
            //  alert(art);// this is the alert which is showing array of objects.
            len = result.data.onwardflights[1].origin;
            alert(len);
        }
    }
});
```

This is the JSON tree .

```
{
"data": {
    "returnflights": [], 
    "onwardflights": [
        {
            "origin": "delhi", 
            "status": "V", 
            "DepartureTime": "21:14", 
            "cancellationPolicy": "0:4:100:0;4:12:25:0;12:-1:10:0", 
            "cCount": 0, 
            "farebasis": "0", 
            "seat": "ST",
```

Comment: Is result an array of object ?

Comment: Note that JavaScript arrays start with index `0`. Using `onwardflights[1]` attempts to access the 2nd element. So, does `"onwardflights"` have multiple elements? Does the 2nd also have an `"origin"`?

Comment: i just edited the code and put the JSON tree . and yes this array of objects

Comment: then you have to use result[0].data to access the first element of result

Comment: It's not valid JSON. That's your problem.

Comment: Please learn how to construct testcases. You won't be able to adequately debug your problems until you do. http://sscce.org

Comment: its valid . i used this in another code and if its not a valid json then why it shows an array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if result is an array

```
len = result[0].origin;
            alert(len);
```

Comment: mukesh i am getting this error TypeError: result[0].data is undefined

Comment: can you just post what's your result contain

Comment: you mean to say i show you the console.log(result); right?

Comment: Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 59 more… ]

Comment: can you post the  console.log(result[0]) also

Comment: Object { origin: "delhi", status: "V", DepartureTime: "21:14", cancellationPolicy: "0:4:100:0;4:12:25:0;12:-1:10:0", cCount: 0, farebasis: "0", seat: "ST", rowid: "BUS@BUSFARESEARCHREQUEST@83ab63fe-9dbd-11e4-b880-40f2e9692cf0", duration: "-22h 45m", qtype: "bus", 27 more… }

Comment: then your result contains the onwardflights array you can use result[0].origin directly

Answer (score 0):

First you need to see what in result.

After you need to find in json tree, your data and keep in mind that **onwardflights** must be **array** and have property that you need.

```
 callbacks: {
        afterFilter: function(result) {
            $('#total_movies').text(result.length);
            //  alert(art);// this is the alert which is showing array of objects.
            len = result.data.onwardflights[0].origin;
            alert(len);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i just edited my code and put the JSON tree . please take a look at that

Comment: i did the same thing but showing an error data is not defined

Comment: can you show for me your console log for your result

Comment: TypeError: result.data is undefined

Comment: it's tell for you that in your afterFilter no argument result that must have json.